# Styling of line spacing in WebVTT cues

Tags: html5-video

I'm attempting to add some basic styling to the `::cue`s from a WebVTT in a `<video>` element. The specific problem is with the `line-height`, or rather the line spacing - which seems to scale depending on the size of the `<video>` element.

The `::cue` pseudo-element only [allows a small subset of CSS properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::cue), of which `line-height` is one of them. Using this I can define a `font-size` and `line-height`, but the `line-height` seems to be ignored.

Here's some basic CSS:

```
video::cue {
  font-size: 14px !important;
  line-height: 20px !important; // or calc(1em + 6px)
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6) !important;
}
```

The `font-size` and `background-color` styles appear to work as expected. Though when the viewport is shrunk, the `font-size` starts to scale down to fit in the `<video>` element.

The `line-height` is mostly disregarded, with multiple lines being spaced according to the size of the video element. Here are some screenshots showing the `<video>` element at various sizes.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I have tried styling the `::cue` with CSS in the document, and as a `::cue` style within the `.vtt` file.

At small sizes the lines begin overlapping, aand at larger sizes the lines are spaced far apart.

Is there a way to consistently style the `::cue` elements so the line spacing stays consistent as the `<video>` element is scaled up/down? Meaning the line spacing would be a constant X pixels?

Note: I'm only need this to work in Chrome.

Comment: Seems like this has become a no-repro: https://jsfiddle.net/v4srthqw/

Comment: line-height in the fiddle above doesn't seem to be affecting Safari. Is there a workaround for Safari?